# How to change the admin phtml files

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-panel

In the order table if create a custom field, now i want that field in the "Sales/order/info" how can i do this? And is it possible to do this without creating a module?
I'm using magento 1.9

Comment: so in the detail view of an order? In the `sales/order/view/info.phtml` template file you mean?

Comment: extend _afterToHtml method, or hang on event core_block_abstract_to_html_after. Look at the similar topic http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17197/extending-admin-order-data/64062#64062

Comment: @SanderMangel Yes that's correct. I add a field in the database and want the value of this field is in the detail view of the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a module might be tricky. You will need a layout XML file and a template file.

You can find the code below as a module on [my Bitbucket page](https://bitbucket.org/sander_mangel/sama_orderinfo/)

the layout XML

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_view>
   <reference name="order_info">
      <action method="setTemplate"><template>mymodule/sales/order/view/info.phtml</template></action>
      <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_view_info" name="original_order_info" template="sales/order/view/info.phtml"></block>
   </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_view>
```

And in the template file we'll call the old `info.phtml` and add any info you want extra above or below that. `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/mymodule/sales/order/view/info.phtml`

```
<?php
/**
 * here you can do whatever you want
 */
?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('original_order_info');?>
```

Extending the `_afterHtml` method or using an observer means using code to fix a layout method. IMO not the best way to go about it.

Comment: I've tried this, but it doesn't work. The new template file isn't loading in te panel, even when i change the path in the layout XML to the Original it's still not showing. How can this happen?

Comment: I'll take a look later on after work to see what the issue is. Currently not on a laptop

Comment: Hi @Esther create a small module that does the basic wrapping. Edit the `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/sama_orderinfo/infowrapper.phtml` with whatever you need

Comment: @Esther did you manage to take a look at the code I wrote?

Comment: Sorry i did not have the time to look into this. I have another project that needs my attention at this moment. I hoop i have time begin next week to check this. I will let you know what my findings are.

Comment: ah ok, no problem. Good luck!

Comment: Ah good to hear, glad it helped. If you need any explanation about elements in the module let me know